# Calling intents from an activity without using buttons or any other user input

Tags: android, android-activity, sensors, android-intent

I have two apps that both extend activities and work perfect on their own, but when I call intent of one to view data in the other the app crashes. I have taken the second and made it a separate java file in my app. Also, I have updated the manifest to include this new activity. Where do I call the intent? If all I want from the second activity is for it to get data and return data should I use startactivityforresult instead? The main thing I want to do is get sensor data from the orientation sensor and show it on my display while still running the original activity.
This is how I call the second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LeanAngle.class);{
      startActivity(intent);
```

Maybe the problem is where I am calling it. Is there a specific place to call it? Also, it has the same view as the main activity does, r.layout.main.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it correctly. I assume your placement is wrong. It will only work if it is the last thing you call in onCreate(). If that is indeed where it is located.